# How to close an Android menu after custom menu item click?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have a problem closing a Xamarin Forms Android custom menu item after clicking on it.

In my MainActivity class I have:

```
public override void OnActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode)
{
    IMenu menu = mode.Menu;
    menu.Add("To Notes");
    menu.GetItem(0).SetOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener(this));

    base.OnActionModeStarted(mode);
}
```

My handler is as follows:

```
public class MyMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, IMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener
{
    private MainActivity mContext;
    public Func<string, Task<string>> EvaluateJavascript { get; set; }

    public MyMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener(MainActivity activity)
    {
        this.mContext = activity;
    }

    public bool OnMenuItemClick(IMenuItem item)
    {
        //Web is a static class declared elsewhere
        Web.CopyToMainNotes();

        return true;
    }
}
```

When clicking on my "To Notes" menu item the menu doesn't disappear, regardless of what's in the OnMenuItemClick handler.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code: (with [ActionMode.finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html#finish()))

```
public override void OnActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode)
{
    IMenu menu = mode.Menu;
    menu.Add("To Notes");
    menu.GetItem(0).SetOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener(this,mode));

    base.OnActionModeStarted(mode);
}
```

**Handler**

```
public class MyMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, IMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener
{
    private MainActivity mContext;
    public Func<string, Task<string>> EvaluateJavascript { get; set; }
    private ActionMode actionMode;

    public MyMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener(MainActivity activity,ActionMode mode)
    {
        this.mContext = activity;
        this.actionMode=mode;
    }

    public bool OnMenuItemClick(IMenuItem item)
    {
        //Web is a static class declared elsewhere
        Web.CopyToMainNotes();
        //close menu if menu item is clicked
        if(actionMode!=null){
        actionMode.finish()
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: glad to help :D @HenryFive